# RemoteNotifications not registering/not doing anything

Tags: iphone, xcode, notifications

I have followed this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12
fully, and after seing that I had issues with my app I even created the same app as he did, the simplest possible but still no luck.

My problem: I do
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

in applicationDidfinishLau... and write the two methods didRegister and didFail but I never get a response back from neither of them (having written some stuff in NSLog in both of them).
I am running of iPhone 4 with wifi only activated and internet's fine... however my internet is very slow here in france but even after waiting a long time still nothing... not even didFail..

thanks for your help

Comment: Have you make correct certificates?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, because I am in France I have no cellular network enabled and push notifcations do not seem to work, at least for the first time, when cellular data and 3G are disabled in the phone.

Comment: I thought you said what you on the WiFi, than this means what registration for remote notification should complete. With remote notification cellular data help to receive them even if device is "sleeping". When device go to sleep, it turn off WiFi and keep only cellular data channel.

Comment: Yes I know but for some reason it does not get a token while when I tried on a relative's iphone which is connected to the cellular it did. The weird thing is that even if the relative's phone does not have any reception but is on wifi it still gets a token and notifications... It has to be something about the deactivation of 3G and celular data in the settings of my iPhone...